# Creating a tile server so that Leaflet ignores empty tiles from it

Tags: leaflet, gis

I am developing a webservice to return TMS tiles based on the `XYZ` coordinates of each tile.

Everything works fine but for some of the tiles I have no data, so I need to return an empty tile. I was thinking if there is any defined HTTP response state code in the leaflet so that instead of returning an empty tile I can just return that HTTP code and leaflet stops rendering that tile.

I was thinking about returning 404 but it logs inside the user's browser and I don't want this solution.

Comment: Look at the documentation is something like `TileErrorEvent` 
`myLayer.on('tileerror', function(error, tile) { console.log(error); 
 console.log(tile); });`

Comment: @GrzegorzT.But this is for finding which tile has error, I want to return an specific http code that leaflet realize that this tile is empty and stops processing that tile

Comment: What does it mean that the tile is empty? You can explain what you mean.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Well I am rendering some points using `leaflet.vectorgrid` plugin which is similar to regular raster tiles but the tiles are in vector. So there is a possibility that in some tiles there is not any points. In my current implimentation I easily return a pbf file with no features inside. But was thinking if there is any way to instead of sending an empty tile(with no feature) I only send an http code (like 404 not found) and leaflet considers that as an empty tile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet handles tile load/error at [this specific bit of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/d1a1e97b8290f642eb677284af53c2db64199a76/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L137-L140):

> ```
>   var tile = document.createElement('img');
>
>   DomEvent.on(tile, 'load', Util.bind(this._tileOnLoad, this, done, tile));
>   DomEvent.on(tile, 'error', Util.bind(this._tileOnError, this, done, tile));
> ```

As long as the [`HTMLImageElement` instance triggers an `error` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Errors), leaflet will trigger the fallback behaviour and try to load [`errorTileUrl`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-errortileurl) into the failed tile.

Leaflet does **not** care why the tile failed, as long as the web browser reported it to fail. As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Errors , this can happen in a lot of situations, including:

- A `40x` or `50x` HTTP error code
- A timeout
- Wrong or unknown image format (e.g. [`.webp` in unsupported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=webp))
- Tried to load something which is not an image. This happens in WMS services, where the WMS server returns an error encapsulated in some XML document.
- ... and more

If you are developing a tile server, and don't want to send 404 HTTP status codes to the browser **even if that's the semantically correct thing to do**, you can just return anything which is not an image.

In particular, the second most semantically appropriate thing to do IMO would be a [`204 No Content` HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) together with a `Content-Length` HTTP header having a value of `0`.

BTW keep in mind that *all* network requests are logged in web browsers, and having 404s is not detrimental to performance or accessibility.

Comment: @IvanSabchez Wow, This was my answer, Thank you so much.